# Erro ao inserir jSON no MySQL com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tenho um código `PHP` que faz com que um array se torne `jSON`

```
<?php
$imagens = array('imagem1.jpg', 'imagem2.jpg', 'imagem3.jpg');

$json = json_encode($imagens);

$inserir = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('$nome', '$descricao', '$foto', '".$json."'));
?>
```

Mas ao executar essa query, o PHP me retorna:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>   '72249.jpg\",\"66462.jpg\",\"84186.jpg\",\"96462.jpg\",\"80447.jpg\"]\")' at line 1

Estou com esse problema, mas não sei o que pode ser.

Comment: Parece que o json está gerando um sintaxe errada no insert, talvez por causa de um barra `\`

Comment: @rray como posso arrumar isso ?

Comment: Coloca a sql gerada.

Comment: Você quer o "CREATE TABLE..." ?

Comment: Faz assim: `$sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('$nome', '$descricao', '$foto', '$json'"; echo $sql; mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: `INSERT INTO acoluna_casos VALUES (\"\", \"teste\", \"<p>testandooo<\/p>\r\n\", \"36681.jpg\", \"[\"06004.jpg\",\"96354.jpg\",\"03715.jpg\",\"87790.jpg\",\"72602.jpg\"]\")` Esse é o comando Real que estou utilizando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pare de usar todas as funções que comece com mysql_* e proíba elas no seu código. Essas funções estão descontinuadas e foram removidas na última versão do PHP (PHP 7). Usar o INSERT da maneira que você está usando não é seguro e está exposto a [SQL Injections](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).

Use a classe [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

```
// Conexão com o banco de dados
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=servidor_bd;dbname=nome_do_banco', $usuario, $senha);

...

$imagens = json_encode(array('imagem1.jpg', 'imagem2.jpg', 'imagem3.jpg'));

$sql = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES (:nome, :descricao, :foto, :imagens)';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':descricao', $descricao, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':foto', $foto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':imagens', $imagens, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Boa tarde. Seria bom explicar por que não usar. Se você sói fala que a pessoa não deve usar, ela não entenderá o motivo.

Comment: Olá @WallaceMaxters, já adicionei a explicação. Obrigado.

Comment: Acho melhor editar, não são proibidas, elas estão apenas em desuso e no php7 foram removidas definitivamente ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, eu quis dizer pra ele proibir o uso de funções mysql_* no próprio código dele.

Comment: Ah entendi, mas é que mesmo assim soa estranho, até pra mim, imagine pra ele que esta começando agora :) Ficou boa a edição agora.

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
 mysql_real_espace_string(json_encode($imagens));
```

Já alerto desde já que funções `mysql_` são descontinuadas em versões recentes do PHP. Você deve migrar pra `mysqli_` ou `PDO`.

Leitura recomendada:

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Prefira não usar a API antiga `mysql_`, tente mysqli ou pdo, pois terá a opção do `bind` que assim evitará também este tipo de problema com os caracteres.

Veja esta resposta:

- [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/3635)

Nota: Como esta na [resposta do @JorgeB.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104478/3635) também falta uma aspas no final `"`

Para resolver o problema atual pode-se deve escapar os apóstrofos (aspas simples) `'`, tente o `mysql_real_escape_string`:

```
$json = mysql_real_escape_string($json);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('$nome', '$descricao', '$foto', '". $json ."'"));
```

No entanto é altamente recomendado migrar para mysqli ou pdo:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $nome, $descricao, $foto, $json);

$stmt->execute();

printf("%d linhas inseridas.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

//Fecha o stmt
$stmt->close();


//Fecha a conexão
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Guilherme está errada a sua resposta, falta ali umas aspas antes de fechar o último parêntesis.

Comment: Esse era o real problema a falta das aspas ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Corrigi, mas ainda pela mensagem de erro `You have an error in your SQL syntax;`, acho que a falta do `"` foi só na hora de colocar aqui na pergunta, acho que é metade do erro :)

Comment: Guilherme pode ter sido, ou não, como está agora só posso tirar essa conclusão.

Answer (score 0):

É simples falta-lhe uma `"` no código antes do último parêntesis:

```
$inserir = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('$nome', '$descricao', '$foto', '".$json."')");
```

Como disse o Wallace Maxters e muito bem prefira as funções [`mysqli_`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php).

Mais explicações: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)