# Ao clicar um botão executar um php

Tags: php, jquery

É possivel eu mesclar o **php** com o **jQuery**? Por exemplo, quando clicasse em um botão pegasse o valor de um input via **jQuery** e passasse para o php, um exemplo do que eu gostaria de fazer:

```
$('btn').on('click', function(){
<?php
// ID de exemplo
$id = 1;
// Selecionando nome da foto do usuário
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT foto FROM usuarios WHERE id = '".$id."'");
$usuario = mysql_fetch_object($sql);
// Removendo usuário do banco de dados
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE id = '".$id."'");
// Removendo imagem da pasta fotos/
unlink("fotos/".$usuario->foto."");
?>});
```

Seria possível?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É possível, mas não dessa maneira. Você tem que criar uma função ajax e chamar um outro script PHP quando o botão é clicado, da maneira que você fez o código PHP é sempre executado quando a página é visitada, não importando se o evento click é executado.

Um exemplo simples:

```
$('btn').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/script.php",
        data: { id: 1 }
    }).done(function() {
       alert('Script executado.');
    })
});
```

[Mais informações sobre $.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

script.php

```
<?php
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
// Selecionando nome da foto do usuário
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT foto FROM usuarios WHERE id = " .$id);
$usuario = mysql_fetch_object($sql);
// Removendo usuário do banco de dados
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE id = " . $id);
// Removendo imagem da pasta fotos/
unlink("fotos/".$usuario->foto."");
```

Não use mais funções que comece com mysql_, [mais informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104473/7334).